# Performing C# (procedural) migrations with DbUp

Tags: dbup

Using [DbUp](https://dbup.readthedocs.io/), is it possible to write a procedural migration in C# (rather than SQL)?

I realise the general philosophy of DbUp is to do everything in SQL but there might be cases where C# is the better tool for the job.

For example let's say you're storing serialized binary blobs in your database (ignoring whether that's a good idea or not) and you want to alter the structure of those blobs. Your application code has the know-how to deserialize/serialize those blobs. Doing so might be *possible* via SQL, but doing it via C# would be simpler.

Is there a way to do this (other than `IScript`)? Basically I'm looking for a mechanism to

- Allow issuing arbitary commands against the database in the context of a transaction
- If the transation completes succesfully, record that "migration" as having completed

`IScript` seems like the closest thing there is - wondering if there is something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - see https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#code-based-scripts

> Code-based scripts Sometimes migrations may require more logic than is
>   easy or possible to perform in SQL alone. Code-based scripts provide
>   the facility to generate SQL in code, with an open database connection
>   and a System.Data.IDbCommand factory provided.
>
> The code-based migration is a class that implements the IScript
>   interface. The ProvideScript() method is called when it is the
>   migration's turn to be executed, so the scripts before it have already
>   been executed.
>
> Of course, the command factory can be used for more than just queries.
>   The entire migration itself can be performed in code:
>
> ```
> public class Script0006UpdateInCode : IScript
> {
>     public string ProvideScript(Func<IDbCommand> commandFactory)
>     {
>         var command = commandFactory();
>
>         command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo]( [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL )";
>         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
>
>         return "";
>     }
> }
> ```